# What is the proper HTML and ARIA construction of a menu with checkboxes that works with JAWS?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have a menu that consists of checkboxes, where the user selects one or more things to display on the screen. My HTML (Angular -- the `*ngFor` directive generates multiple `<li>` blocks) looks like this:

```
<ul role="menu" [id]="'topic-menu' + i" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'topic-menu' + i + 'label'">
  <li
    [id]="'topic-option' + i + j"
    *ngFor="let measure of group.measures; let j = index"
    class="topic-option"
    role="none"
  >
    <input
      class="checkbox-input"
      type="checkbox"
      role="menuitemcheckbox"
      [attr.aria-labelledby]="'topic-select-input-label' + i + j"
      [name]="'group' + i + '-topic-menu'"
      [checked]="measure.selected"
      [id]="'topic-select-input' + i + j"
      (click)="onSelectCheckboxMultiple(measure, group.measures)"
    >
    <label
      [for]="'topic-select-input' + i + j"
      [id]="'topic-select-input-label' + i + j"
      class="topic-select-label"
    >
      {{ measure.measureName }}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I listen to this, JAWS announces the menu, lists the number of items, and says "to move through items press up or down arrow". However, the user cannot use up or down arrows, and instead must tab through the checkboxes. As far as I can tell, this is the expected behavior of checkboxes -- see here: https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/checkbox/checkbox-1/checkbox-1.html).

I am confused as to how I should modify my HTML to make JAWS and the behavior get on the same page. Here is an example of a menu that uses role="menuitemcheckbox", and indeed, you can navigate those options with up/down keys, as JAWS instructs, but you can see that they do not actually use `input` elements. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-2/menubar-2.html

It seems like I need to choose between using `role="menu"` and using `<input type="checkbox">`, but I have no idea which is the correct strategy. Note that I am not in fact using a `<form>`, so, the no `<input>` option is possible.

Can anyone offer guidance here?

Comment: "to move through items press up or down arrow" is being announce because of the `role="menu"` I think. Do you need role menu? Why have checkboxes in a menu?  On the LIs, try `role="presentation"` instead of `role="none"`

Comment: @2pha The "widget", to use W3.org speak, allows users to select which variables will be shown in a display. This seems like a menu -- and it seems like it fits the W3.org definition of a menu -- to me. And it seems reasonable to announce to users that something is a menu, with X number of options. 

But I have no idea if I "need" role=menu.

Comment: Personally, I would not put it in a role menu. I would probably not have a list at all and put the checkboxes in a div with role=group and have an aria-label, or, use a fieldset and legend. But without really knowing more, my comments are just guesses on what you need. I just completed a large government site which needed  accessibility with JAWS, Iphone and android. It was a nightmare.

Comment: Having another thought, maybe adding `role="menuItem"` on the LIs gets you what you want, but I suspect the fact that the menuItems having checkboxes inside may cause problems, especially with respect to screen readers going in and out of "form mode"

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions @2pha (and sympathy). I wound up looking at a number of additional examples -- MS's Accessibility website, and a demo on the Freedom Scientific (maker of JAWS) site itself, and noticed that many things that could be called "menus" in the lay sense of the term were not getting any role markup -- they were just `ul` and `li` lists. I decided to go with that, and to use the header elements that I have on the screen visibly above the lists as aria-labelled as text, so that JAWS essentially reads exactly what is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to mark up accessible menus which persistently display a selected or checked menu item is through the menuitemradio role as shown in [this example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-2/menubar-2.html) from the [ARIA authoring practices documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#menu). Per guidelines, the menuitem role does not permit the aria-checked attribute, but menuitemradio does. Where multiple items can be checked, the menuitemcheckbox role should be used.